# Check for username availability php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','[mypassword]','dbhwsource');

if(isset($_GET['username'])){
$username = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$test = $con->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
if($test!=false) die("usererror");
}

if(isset($_GET['email'])){
$email = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$test = $con->query("select * from users where email='$email'");
if($test!=false) die("emailerror");
}

$con->close();
echo "ok";
?>
```

So I'm just trying to check to see if the username / email is available or not, but all i get is "usererror" no matter what the input username is! I'm just frustrated and have searched for sample code everywhere and the code looks like there's nothing wrong with it. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
$test = $test->fetch_assoc();
if(!empty($test)) die("usererror");
```

This worked!

Comment: why the vote down... :(

Comment: 1. Avoid SQL injection by using prepared statements. 2. Add the error message i.e. `$con->error` to get more information about what is the nature of the error

Comment: 1. I'm using escape strings so shouldn't that prevent SQLi? 2. There are NO errors or else I'd post them here.

Comment: +1 to offset the incorrect downvote.

Comment: thanks. I didn't quite get why I was downvoted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$test = $test->fetch_assoc();
if(!empty($test)) die("usererror");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your query returns true, this line `if($test!=false) die("usererror");` gets executed,
should be something like

```
$test = $con->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$row_cnt = $test->num_rows;
if( $row_cnt > 0 ) { 
  //you already have user with this name, do something 
}
```

Comment: row count returned 1 for me everytime.

Answer (score 1):

`$con->query` returns a *result object* if the *query was successful*. This doesn't say anything about how many rows where found or whether the query matched anything, it just means the query executed successfully. Therefore your `$test!=false` test *always* succeeds; only in the case of a database error would it fail.

Do the query as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`, then fetch the first row of the result and see if the count is `> 0`.

Comment: Well yes, it's a Mysqli object. Don't use mysql functions on it, use Mysqli methods to fetch results!

Comment: oh that's right i feel so dump! :/ so now I'm getting Undefined index. for checking index 0. Im going to check row numbers...

Comment: I tried a new code, but it's still not working. please check the edit.

Comment: i managed to fix it with empty() and fetch_assoc. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something like this for an android app. you should really check [this site](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) out. It helped me tremendously. This is a detailed example of having a PHP API for an aplication. Specifically logging in.

To be specific though, here is a snippet from the page for the PHP

```
/*
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function isUserExisted($email) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        // user existed
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes using this ONLY will fail. you have to have the rest of the api together. If you follow the link I gave you. It go into extreme details. I used this example to create my own api for my android app. It works great.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is really not secure not optimized anybody can login with sql injection in your code.

and your code is right as you are checking thar (test != false) it means it is true that's why your code og usererror is executing

here is some tips and always use this style for security and optimization

> do same for $email
>
> third after running the query do not check if it is true or false but check again after query

```
if($test->username === $_GET['username']) { do something }
```

> check sql injections on Google why i did this

Comment: im using scape strings so it should be safe... :/

Comment: The real_escape_string fixes the SQL-injection here.